# SQL Query intermittently timing out, Any ALTER immediately fixes it

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I have a pretty basic SQL Query I'm running (SQL Server 2016). I'm pulling about 15 columns from some simple inner and left joins on 8 tables that all have `WITH (NOLOCK)` on the join. My where clause is checking for a few string, uniqueidentifier, and bit values. The stored procedure has no calculations, no loops/cursors/case statements, etc..  It is very straightforward.

For some reason our application keeps intermittently freezing up because the SQL call is timing out.  When I grab the call in profiler and run it in SSMS it runs in sub-second time, but from the application it just wont finish.

However, if I script out an ALTER command on the query and just add a blank line and execute the change, the problem goes away and the calls run instantaneously. The change I make is nothing substantive, just the act of changing the query in some way seems to unlock it.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this? I don't see any locks when it is timing out. I was thinking maybe a bad execution plan being cached?

The only other oddity is that this is running from an old legacy application, our last one in old classic asp. But it doesn't seem related to the web server or architecture, just the database.

Comment: sounds like a bad execution plan to me.   What have you done to rule out parameter-sniffing?

Comment: See [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: I just added WITH RECOMPILE to the stored procedure to see if that has an effect to combat potential parameter sniffing.  I'm also reading through the NOLOCK article right now.

Comment: I'd highly recommend to read [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) by Erland Sommarskog.